# How can I find a number in a string in DB2 SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I need to find a number in a string in DB2 SQL, 
and I have the position of the first number.

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: What have you already tried? Can you please show some example data?

Comment: SELECT LENGTH(RTRIM(TRANSLATE('ABCDEF123',' ','0123456789'))) ...but not always work :-(

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using Db2 11.1, you should use REGEXP_EXTRACT.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061492.html

E.g.

```
values regexp_extract(' STR. 5TH PALACE WASHINGTONN, 15','\b[0-9]+\b')
```

returns

```
 1
 --
 15
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help
...but I don't know why, I take always a minus sign result on screen. ("-"). 

Maybe regexp_extract or regexp_substr is another version on the AS400 that I use ? 
For example this one work: S
ELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('hello 55 aaa to you', '.o',1,2)     
FROM sysibm.sysdummy1                                     
it give me "to" result. 

Thanks a lot again

Comment: DB2 for i 71.. and above has the same function ( REGEXP_SUBSTR and REGEXP_EXTRACT are synonyms) https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzscaregexp_substr.htm

Comment: Yes... but I don't undestand why some parameters work and some ot work. Tha samples on IBM site is too low in order to undestand.

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: The regexp_substr(str, '[\d]+(?![^\s])') for example... and a lot of other parms :-(

Answer (score 2):

## Solution 1

One or more digits not followed by non-space character.
See the [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzscaregexp_substr.htm) description.

```
select str, regexp_substr(str, '[\d]+(?![^\s])') num
from table(values 
  'STR. WASHINGTONN 15'
, 'STR. WASHINGTONN, 15'
, 'STR. WASHINGTONN NR. 15'
, 'STR. 5TH PALACE WASHINGTONN, 15'
) t(str);
```

BTW:
Seems that [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<![^\s])[\d]+(?![^\s])` (one or more digits not preceded by non-space and not followed by non-space) doesn't work on my DB2 7.3 for IBM i at least, but does work on Db2 11.1.

## Solution 2

We add spaces to both sides of string, if lookahead/lookbehind regexp functionality doesn't work:

```
select str, trim(regexp_substr(' '||str||' ', '\s[\d]+\s')) num
from table(values 
  'STR. WASHINGTONN 15'
, 'STR. WASHINGTONN, 15'
, 'STR. WASHINGTONN NR. 15'
, 'STR. 5TH PALACE WASHINGTONN, 15'
) t(str);
```

Comment: Mark...on your query i receive this error:   1 -- The external program or service program returned SQLSTATE 2201S. The
text message returned from the program is:                                 
REGEXP_SUBSTR [\d]+(?![^\s]) .                    :-(

Comment: Do you know how can I see the vers. of my DB2 please ?

Comment: Try this: `select release_level from qsys2.license_info where product_text='IBM i' and usage_type='*REGISTERED'`

Comment: We have here the V7R2M0 version. Can be this the reason because it didn't work please ? Thanks again

Comment: `SQLSTATE 2201S` is wrong regexp pattern. Try _Solution 2_.

Comment: You may try the following as well as in Paul's example: `regexp_substr(str, '\b[\d]+\b')`

Answer (score 0):

You're probably interested in [LOCATE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000820.html?pos=2) or [REGEXP_INSTR](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061493.html?pos=2) functions but it's really hard to tell from the information given. REGEXP_INSTR is relatively new so you'll need to check if it's available in your version of Db2 on your platform.

Comment: I have something like: 

STR. WASHINGTONN 15 
or: 
STR. WASHINGTONN, 15 
or: 
STR. WASHINGTONN NR. 15 
or: 
STR. 5TH PALACE WASHINGTONN, 15 
And I must take out the 15 number 

I don't know the version of DB2 but the OS of iSeries is 7.2

Thanks a lot. 
Denis

Comment: How can I use LOCATE but with indentify all numerics chars please ? Thanks again